# Visual Studios C# Nunit Test Explorer does not show individual test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZB2o.png)

[My Test Explorer should have an option to collapse each test to individually see the pass/failed test. Is there an option/view on visual studio that allows me to reset that option? as it was fine before. If not is there away to restore default settings for Nunit test in Visual Studios?]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have maximized the Group Summary window?

If this is the case hover over the left hand side of the Test Explorer windows and you will see the (<==>) double arrow.

Left click and hold and move to the right to reveal the test list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Alex you literally saved my life from getting deducted 10% for late submission 